# Launch not main activity from another application

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have two application. Let say: appA and appB

AppA have the manifest such as below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".EditItemActivity" android:exported="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Next AppB create a custom notification:

```
public void CustomNotification() {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.mynotification);

    int idProduct = 1;

    Intent intent_anotherApp = new Intent();
    intent_anotherApp.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.hfade.appA", "com.hfade.appA.ListActivity"));  //does not works

    Intent launchIntent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.hfade.appA"); //works but only mainActivity

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("pid", idProduct);
    intent_anotherApp.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            launchIntent,        // or intent_anotherApp
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"})
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, channelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtTitle,"title");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.firstLine,"sometext");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.secondLine,"text");

    nm.notify(id++, builder.build());
}
```

However there I have a problem. When I pass this to pendingIntent:

`Intent launchIntent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.hfade.appA");`

it works but it opens only a front-door activity (MainActivity)
And When I try to use this approach:

```
Intent intent_anotherApp = new Intent();
    intent_anotherApp.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.hfade.appA", "com.hfade.appA.ListActivity"));
```

as arg in pendingActivity that does not work.

Does not works such I expected (no error, I guess the problem is that there no "startActivity()")
So I know how to open com.hfade.appA.MainActivity but no: com.hfade.appA.ListActivity

Can you help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I found out the solution -

```
Intent intent_anotherApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent_anotherApp.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.hfade.appA", "com.hfade.appA.ListActivity"));
```

So it was about Intent.ACTION_MAIN as arg for new Intent.